# How to protect SecIdentity with biometrics/kSecAttrAccessControl?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

Here's the repo where this can be easily reproduced: https://github.com/haemi/SecIdentityBiometrics

What I try to achieve is generating a RSA 2048bit key pair, where the public key is sent to the server. The server sends a x.509 certificate back.

With my private key and the certificate, I need to create a SecIdentity (used for URLAuthChallenge). This works when I do not use biometrics to protect the private key.

But as soon as I add biometrics, I'm unable to fetch the SecIdentity. I tried with two variants:

```
enum Variant {
    case writeIdentityWithBiometrics
    case writePrivateKeyWithBiometrics
}
```

writeIdentityWithBiometrics

Here I add kSecAttrAccessControl to the private key directly and try to read the SecIdentity in the end.

writePrivateKeyWithBiometrics

Here I first add the keypair, then the certificate to the keychain - everything without biometrics. Then I read the SecIdentity and try to add it with kSecAttrAccessControl.